# FFmpeg - how to set output sample_size

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, output, 24-bit

Trying to create a simple command line player for .dsf (DSD audio) files, and output to an alsa device that supports up to 24-bit 192 kHz sample rate.  The following command almost works and it does play the track.  Examining the bold text below, the dsf input file is converted to 24-bit/192 kHz, but the output is then truncated to 16-bit 192 kHz (pcm_s16le i.e, 16 bit little endian).

ffmpeg -i '01 - Sweet Georgia Brown.dsf' -f alsa hw:0,0

After displaying the ffmpeg banner and song metadata (tags), here is the result, bold is my emphasis:

Duration: 00:05:14.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9234 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, **192000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)**
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flac (native) -> **pcm_s16le** (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, alsa, to 'hw:0,0':

Since I can play this and many other tracks at full resolution using another player (foobar2000) it seems there might be an option in the encoder which is part of FFmpeg: Lavf57.83.100   I can find no information in any of the FFmpeg documentation that helps.  Tried finding options in FFplay and even guessing using other FFmpeg options like this example.
ffmpeg -sample_fmt s24 -i '01 - Sweet Georgia Brown.dsf' -f alsa hw:0,0  ***** same results.

I'm stuck.  Any suggestions?

Environment: Linux Mint 19.2, 64-bit, ASUS Xonar STXii sound card.

Answer (score 0):

Each output format or device has a default encoder registered for each media type it accepts. ALSA accepts audio and its default encoder is 16-bit signed PCM.

You can change the encoder by specifying one.

```
ffmpeg -i '01 - Sweet Georgia Brown.dsf' -c:a pcm_s24le -f alsa hw:0,0
```

Comment: YES!  That's it, thank you so much.  Now I need to go back into the docs and understand the -c:a option.  I up-voted your answer, it tells me newbies can up-vote but until I get a reputation over 15 it won't show, but will still count.

Comment: Here's the actual text:  Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score